# Is there a way to invoke a collection of methods at once using reflection Java?

Tags: java, selenium

Basically I am running selenium tests with the use of a DataProvider and a single base method that is the starting point to invoke all of my tests. The test methods are in a different class and I want to be able to invoke all of the methods at once since I am running the tests in parallel instead of one at a time (serially).  Is there a way to do that? Below is the main code:

```
 @Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = DataProviderUtils.REGRESSION, dataProviderClass = DataProviderUtils.class)
public void test(String env, String browser, String title, String id, String orderType, String productType, String isFreeShipping, String isTaxState,
                      String billingCountry, String shippingCountry, String promoType, String isPromoFree,
                      String isPromoCode, String noOfPromoCodes, String email, Object[] customSteps){

    driverUtils.setUp(browser);

    Class[] classes = {UseCases.class};
    for(Class clazz : classes){
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method method : methods){
            try {
                method = clazz.getMethod(method.getName(), new Class[]{String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Object[].class});
                Object invoke = method.invoke(new UseCases(), id, env, productType, isFreeShipping, isTaxState, billingCountry, customSteps);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
@Test(enabled = true, dataProvider = DataProviderUtils.REGRESSION, dataProviderClass = DataProviderUtils.class)
public void test(final String env, String browser, String title, final String id, String orderType, final String productType, final String isFreeShipping, final String isTaxState, final String billingCountry,
        String shippingCountry, String promoType, String isPromoFree, String isPromoCode, String noOfPromoCodes, String email, final Object[] customSteps) {

    driverUtils.setUp(browser);

    Class[] classes = { UseCases.class };
    for (final Class clazz : classes) {

        Runnable runnableClass = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (final Method method : methods) {
                    Runnable runnableMethod = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                method = clazz.getMethod(method.getName(), new Class[] { String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Object[].class });
                                Object invoke = method.invoke(new UseCases(), id, env, productType, isFreeShipping, isTaxState, billingCountry, customSteps);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    Thread threadMethod = new Thread(runnableMethod);
                    System.out.println("Start Thread Class: " + clazz + " Method: " + method);
                    threadMethod.start();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread threadClass = new Thread(runnableClass);
        System.out.println("Start Thread Class: " + clazz);
        threadClass.start();
    }
}
```

in this sample i use two threads for run Classes and methods in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CountDownLatch class of the java.util.concurrent package. Create a pool of Threads and with the CountDownLatch object start them at once.